# Classroom Orphaned by deleted teacher account

Tags: google-classroom

My predecessor was in the habit of deleting users from gsuite. This has resulted in 18 courses that I cannot figure out how to change from ACTIVE to ARCHIVED.

GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/#######?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

```
{
  "id": "#######",
  "name": "Course Name",
  "ownerId": "#####################",
  "creationTime": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "updateTime": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "enrollmentCode": "xx#xxx#",
  "courseState": "ACTIVE",
  "alternateLink": "https://classroom.google.com/c/XXX#XXXxXxxx",
  "teacherGroupEmail": "Course_Name_teachers_#xXxXx@domain.com",
  "courseGroupEmail": "Course_Name--#xXxXx@comain.com",
  "teacherFolder": {
    "id": "#X#Xx#xxX#xXXxXXXX#xXxXXxxXx"
  },
  "guardiansEnabled": false
}
```

Trying to PATCH the class to ARCHIVED:

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/#######?updateMask=courseState&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"courseState":"ARCHIVED"}' \
  --compressed
```

Returns error 500:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you the domain administrator? I don't see any problem with your request, it could just be temporary.

Comment: The account I'm using to call the API is a Super Admin. The call works fine on classes where  the teacher account for the class still exists. Only fails with the 500 code on the 18 courses where the user account that created the classroom was deleted.

Comment: I see, can you list all the courses from your Super Admin account? Do you see the orphaned ones as well?

Comment: Yes. The orphaned classes are listed as active classes and I haven't been able to figure out how to set them to archived without receiving a 500 error. I've tried transferring ownership to a new userID, but the API returns the error that ownership can only be transferred to co-teachers. I haven't been able add a teacher to those courses either. These courses are basically zombies.

Comment: Here is a link to an article describing my exact situation: https://www.amplifiedit.com/orphaned-google-classroom-classes/ I reached out to the author for more details about how to use GAM or API Explorer as mentioned, but have not gotten a reply.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760244 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888984/500-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-delete-certain-courses
https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6071551

According to google, currently no solution. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760244#comment13

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug that Google seems to be aware of and has no solution at this time.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760244#comment13